# Does composed primary keys works as index when called separately?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have an table structure like this:

```
| id_something | id_something_else | id_something_elsewhere | data
```

And declare the three id's as an unitary composite primary key, then, when manipulating my data, I call `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_something = x;`.

Querying like this, my composite key would increase performance like a simple index? Or this would only take effect when calling the three keys at the same query?
Furthermore, in order to increase performance, should I create simple unitary indices for every key I want to query in this table?

Comment: MySQL has pretty good documentation on multi-column indexes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.  You should start by reading that.

Comment: I read, then I started using leftmost index to perform queries, but didn't noticed performance impact on having or not having the primary key, like it isn't working.

Comment: How large is your table?  Perhaps the query is already using another index.  You need to look at the query plan to see what is happening.

Comment: Reasonably large (~10k records). The problem is that I have to update multiple records with different where clauses at once and, how the "where's" are different from each other, I cannot make a single query, having to perform a "for" loop updating record by record.